# How I create a EventHandler for a Button in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, listview, event-handling

My Problem:

I have a ASP.NET Application and use a ListView. I get Datalines (eMail,Username,Firstname etc..) from the Active Directory and fill this in my ListView. Every Line has a Button "Show", with this Button I want to a other WebForm. With a Session I surrender the Data to the other WebForm.
My Code:

> ```
>     <LayoutTemplate>
>         <table id="UserTable" runat="server" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="5">
>             <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
>                 <th id="Th1" runat="server">Benutzer</th>
>                 <th id="Th2" runat="server">eMail</th>
>                 <th id="Th3" runat="server">Vorname</th>
>                 <th id="Th4" runat="server">Nachname</th>
>                 <th id="Th5" runat="server">Telefon</th>
>             </tr>
>             <tr runat="server" id="ItemPlaceholder">
>             </tr>
>         </table>
>     </LayoutTemplate>
>
>     <ItemTemplate>
>
>         <tr runat="server"> 
>
>             <td align="left" ><asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%# Eval("Benutzer") %>' runat="server" /></td>
>             <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label2" Text='<%# Eval("eMail") %>' runat="server" /></td>
>             <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label3" Text='<%# Eval("Vorname") %>' runat="server" /></td>
>             <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label4" Text='<%# Eval("Nachname") %>' runat="server" /></td>
>             <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label5" Text='<%# Eval("Telefon") %>' runat="server" /></td>
>
>               //Every Line get a Button
>             <td align="left"><asp:Button ID="Button1" Text ="Anzeigen" runat="server" /></td>
>
>         </tr>
>
>     </ItemTemplate>
>
>     </asp:ListView>
> ```

The Button has a onClick= "..." Argument but how I make a Event for this and how I transfer to the other WebForm with the right Session Information. I think I must work with the Index from the Line :/

I need help :(

tarasov

Answer (score 0):

Try this
in your aspx you do

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandArgument='<%# eval("ID") %>' CommandName="Anzeigen" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

in code behind you do

```
    protected void Button1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Anzeigen")
        {
            string sID = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            int id = 0;
            int.TryParse(sID, out id);

            if (id > 0)
            { 
             // do stuff
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Let me know if you don't understand it

Comment: ASP.benutzerliste_aspx" enthält keine Definition für "Button1_Command", und es konnte keine Erweiterungsmethode "Button1_Command" gefunden werden, die ein erstes Argument vom Typ "ASP.benutzerliste_aspx" akzeptiert (Fehlt eine Using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis?).

Comment: benutzerliste_aspx don't have a Definition for Button1_Command.

Comment: Did you add the event void Button1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e) in your aspx.cs file and did you also compiled your code

Comment: Ok ...Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead. XD

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1597279.aspx here is a Example for this what I Search...but this don't work in my Application :/

Comment: void Button1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Anzeigen")
            {
                Response.Redirect("Benutzer.aspx"); 
               
            }
        }

Comment: after you click on the button do you get redirect to benutzer.aspx? and do you pass the ID of the person that you want to edit/update ?

Comment: no i don't redirect to benutze.aspx :( this is my first step, too.

Comment: <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Anzeigen" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandArgument='<%# eval("ID") %>' CommandName="Anzeigen" runat="server" />

Comment: Keine Überladung für "Button1_Command" stimmt mit dem Delegaten "System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventHandler" überein.

No Overdrive for "Button_Command" match with the Delegaten "System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventHandler "

Comment: can you add protected infront of the void so it looks like this protected void Button1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)

Comment: mhh what a bad start to the weekend :( ...can you send me your application to my email or a other way

Comment: Now I must check the line to the email or id and rediredt this to the other webform :P

Comment: Use of the comments section on Stack Overflow for interactive debugging is a misuse of the comments section.  Please refrain from doing so in the future.